# JUnit tests for Quarkus projects no longer respect log4j2.xml in test/resources

Tags: java, junit, log4j2, quarkus, junit-jupiter

I have a `log4j2.xml` in the `src/test/resources` to turn on debug logging during JUnit tests to ensure all code paths are executed. When I try to upgrade to Quarkus 2.7 or higher (I've tried with 2.8 and 2.9), the tests are no longer run with debug logging. This is evident via the jacoco task showing all lines are no longer covered.

Is there a new way I should be going about enabling debug logging during JUnit tests?

Reproducer: `service1` in https://github.com/mweber03/quarkus-test

1. `./gradlew service1:build`
2. `./gradlew service1:jacocoTestCoverageVerification` (succeeds)
3. Change Quarkus version in `gradle.properties` to 2.7 or higher
4. Repeat steps 1 and 2 (fails due to code coverage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the log level in your `application.properties`. E.g. if you want to set the log level only for your tests you can add following configuration property:

```
%test.quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
```

You can find more information about how to configure logging on the quarkus guides: https://quarkus.io/guides/logging

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could've sworn I tried that, smh.